# matlab error: variable 'cell' is used but might be unset : matlab thinks function name is variable name

Tags: matlab

I have a function in matlab that starts as follows:

```
function [W,Y] = myfun(L,nit)
W = cell(L,1);
x = cell(L+1,1);
...
```

So `W` and `x` are initialized as cell arrays of length `L`, and then I proceed to actually do things with them in the body of the function. However, matlab's editor has the red squiggle line under the first usage of `cell` with the message:

```
variable 'cell' is used but might be unset
```

And if I try to call the function in my main script, I get the error:

```
"cell" previously appeared to be used as a function or command, conflicting      
with its use here as the name of a variable.
A possible cause of this error is that you forgot to initialize the 
variable, or you have initialized it implicitly using load or eval.
```

And I do not understand why matlab thinks I am calling `cell` as the name of a variable. I can execute either line

```
W = cell(L,1);
x = cell(L+1,1);
```

outside of this specific function, and they work just as expected. I have created cell arrays in other functions without getting any errors. And if I use the command

```
exist cell
```

I get an answer of 5, indicating that `cell` is still a built-in function. So I am confused.

Comment: This is very strange! What  version of Matlab are you using? In the meantime, you could do `W{L,1}=[]` and `x{L+1,1}=[]` to create your cell arrays.

Comment: So in your main script, if you use `cell` in the line before the call to `myfun` that throws the error, there is no error?

Comment: Have you gone to Tools -> Code Analyzer to see what that gives you?

Comment: @David That does work, thanks for the workaround.

Comment: @zeeMonkeez: Correct

Comment: @CerebralCortexan: Code Analyzer added no new information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turned out I had a typo (much) later in function where I called cell instead of the variable:

```
function [conn] = myfun(nn)

conn = cell(nn,1); 

.
.
.

conn{i} = unique( cell{i} );
```

instead of :

```
conn{i} = unique( conn{i} );
```

Which caused the error.